# Multi tenant nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I'm working to setup a SaaS platform for content creators and educators. I have come to a stage, where I need to setup custom domains for end users. Seeing how its done in industry I have figured to use CNAME record to direct traffic from user` domain to my server.

> CNAME www.customuserdomain.com -> customuseralias.mysaas.io

Then I have configured nginx like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<account>.+)\.mysaas\.io$;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Account $account; 
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5003;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

    }
}
```

When server is accessed via `customuseralias.mysaas.io`. Then when inside my application i have access to *'Account' header* and can determine what to display no problem.

However when server is accessed via `www.customuserdomain.com` I get a bad gateway error. From my investigation I understand that in that case nginx sees incoming request as server `www.customuserdomain.com` and its not handled correctly.

How can I approach resolving this, should I go with wildcard server and process requests application side - this feels like security nightmare? or maybe there is some kind of automation tool that could create vhosts for every new domain? Just thinking out loud, please help :)

Comment: I think the issue is that your request to www.customuserdomain.com are getting redirected without having an account and causing nginx to be unable to handle the request. I would suggest that you perform a `curl -kIL www.customuserdomain.com` and see what is going on with the request. This can also be done with the Chrome developer tools.

Comment: @HeysusEscobar 502 bad gateway error is returned as i had another server {} statement with server_name _ that was pointing to disabled proxy.

However this is not the problem. When request comes to my server it comes from www.customuserdomain.com so $host is the same. my question is how do i know it comes from "customuseralias.mysaas.io" on nginx side or the only way is to either make "server_name _" and handle logic on app side or add entry for every customerdomain to create separate vhosts ?

Comment: Maybe you can do a redirect from `www.customuserdomain.com` via nginx to `customuseralias.mysaas.io` instead as CNAME can be tricky.
`The CNAME record maps a name to another name. It should only be used when there are no other records on that name.` from https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/#:~:text=Use%20a%20CNAME%20record%20if,records%20for%20the%20same%20name.